# HTML and Javascript changing visibility

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried searching this up many times. I have come close, but have not figured this out yet. What I am trying to do is when the user reaches a certain amount of clicks, a button pops up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>++ Increment</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Click the Button</h1>
  <input type="button" id="countButton" onclick="hi()" value="Click Me!"/>
  <p class="ClickCount">Clicks: <a id="amount">0</a></p>
  <input type="button" id="countButton" onclick="store()" value="Store"/>
  <input type="button" style="visibility:hidden;" value="Button" id="Sir" />
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var count = 0;
function hi() {
  count += 1;
  document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = count;
}
if (count >= 20) {
  document.getElementById("Sir").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

I think I need to assign the *count* variable outside the *hi()* function, but I don't know how to do that (or if that's possible)

Comment: Try putting `if (count >= 20) { ... }` inside the function `hi`

Answer (score 1):

From mobile so excuse my pseudo code

Is you're using jquery, you can store the value in a 
$(btn).data('clicks')

Otherwise define a global variable above your hi function.

Then you need to put your logic of if(clicks > 20) inside your hi function

Answer (score 1):

```js
var count = 0;
function store(){
  alert(count);
}
function hi() {
  count += 1;
  document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = count;
  if (count >= 4) document.getElementById('Sir').style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

```css
#Sir{display:none;}
```

```html
<h1>Click the Button</h1>
<input type="button" id="countButton" onclick="hi()" value="Click Me!"/>
<p class="ClickCount">Clicks: <a id="amount">0</a></p>
<input type="button" id="countButton" onclick="store()" value="Store"/>
<input type="button" value="Button" id="Sir" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>++ Increment</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Click the Button</h1>
  <input type="button" id="countButton" value="Click Me!"/>
  <p class="ClickCount">Clicks: <a id="amount">0</a></p>
  <!-- <input type="button" id="countButton" onclick="store()" value="Store"/> -->
  <input type="button" style="visibility:hidden;" value="Button" id="Sir" />
  <script>
        var count = 0;
        var clickbutton = document.getElementById("countButton");
        var showbutton = document.getElementById("Sir");
        var amountstatus = document.getElementById("amount");

        clickbutton.onclick = function(){
            if(count < 3){
                count++;
                amountstatus.innerHTML = count;
            }
            else{
                showbutton.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Check I put this  `<input type="button" id="countButton" onclick="store()" value="Store"/>` in comments, that's why you must not have two id with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Hello can you please give a try to following code below:

```js
var count = 0;
function hi() {
  count += 1;
  document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = count;

  if (count >= 20) {
    document.getElementById("Sir").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

Only change i think to move if condition inside hi function. Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Zakk.  Storing the value in a data attribute would be the best way to do this.  Here's how I'd code it.

```js
$(function() {
  
  $( "#countButton" ).on( "click", function() {
    
    var clicks = $( this ).data( "clicks" );
    clicks++;
    
    // Display the clicks.
    $( "#amount" ).html( clicks );
    $( this ).data( "clicks", clicks );
    
    // Check to see if the sir button should be displayed. 
    if( clicks >= 20 ) {
      
      $( "#Sir" ).css( "visibility", "visible" );
      
    }
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>++ Increment</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Click the Button</h1>
  <input type="button" id="countButton" data-clicks="0" value="Click Me!"/>
  <p class="ClickCount">Clicks: <a id="amount">0</a></p>
  <input type="button" id="countButton" onclick="store()" value="Store"/>
  <input type="button" style="visibility: hidden;" value="Button" id="Sir" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe "best" is an opinion; Especially since I personally don't believe using an element to store the variable and having to reference the element in order to retrieve it would be the best solution (at least not if it can be easily avoided).

Comment: Why add another arbitrary variable when you can keep the data linked with the object that's affecting it?

Comment: I think the question is why tie the data to element when you can create a simple variable to store the value? What's arbitrary about it?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is outside the function hi(), so it is checked once when the file loaded, no when hi() is call.

So you may put your condition inside hi().

```
var count = 0;
function hi() {
  count += 1;
  document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = count;

  if (count >= 20) {
    document.getElementById("Sir").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```